# Upload files (like PDF, image, Word...) to a table in SQL Server using Excel VBA

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba, t-sql

I have an Excel file that a few users are using it as a front-end And I want to be able to upload via VBA a general files (like PDF, image, word document...) to SQL Server.

After searching many sites I put together some code and I dont know what to write in the VBA SQL variable (INSERT INTO query) in order to upload some general file (like PDF for example)

The VBA code:

```vb
Sub SaveAsBinary()

    Dim adoStream As Object
    Dim adoCmd As Object
    Dim strFilePath As String
    Dim adoCon As Object
  
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim FileNameStr as String
  
    
    Set adoCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set adoStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    Set adoCmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    
    '--Open Connection to SQL server
    adoCon.CursorLocation = 3 'adUseClient
    
    adoCon.Open = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};" _
                        & "MyServerName;" _
                        & "Database=MyDatabaseName;" _
                        & "Uid=MyUserName;" _
                        & "Pwd={MyPassword};" _
                        & "Connection Timeout=30;"
    
    
    '----
    
    strFilePath = Range("a1").Value 'keep File path to upload (simple local computer path)
    FileNameStr = Dir(strFilePath )
    
    SQL = "INSERT INTO Tbl_Test VALUES (FileNameStr, ??)" '‹‹---What value should be here for loading a pdf file (for example)

    
    adoStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
    adoStream.Open
    adoStream.LoadFromFile strFilePath 'It fails if file is open
        
    With adoCmd
        .CommandText = SQL ' Query
        .CommandType = 1 ' adCmdText
        
        '---adding parameters
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@FileName", 20, 1, 0, 1)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@MyFile", 204, 1, adoStream.Size, adoStream.Read)
        '---
    End With
    
    adoCmd.ActiveConnection = adoCon
    adoCmd.Execute
        
    adoCon.Close
    
End Sub
```

The original code was taken from:
https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2014/09/30/store-and-fetch-files-sql-server-tables/

The table in Sql server:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tbl_Test](
    [FileName] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [MyFile] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

**One column for the file name and one for the file itself.**

Note: SQL Server is on a remote server without shared folders/BLOB/FTP.

Comment: it's not an error description, it just that i dont know what to write in the SQL "INSERT INTO" query.

Comment: I guess it should be `VALUES (?, ?)` as in the original code. and here you need to specify your filename `.CreateParameter("@FileName")` instead of an ID as in the original code and here `.CreateParameter("@MyFile"` you send your file as `adoStream`.

Comment: Checkout the documentation of the [CreateParameter Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/createparameter-method-ado?view=sql-server-ver15) that should help you too.

Comment: I imagine `.CreateParameter("@FileName", 20, 1, 0, 1)` isn't going to work for you, considering `#define adBigInt 20` and `#define adVarWChar 202`. Try something that includes a size, too, e.g.: `.CreateParameter("@FileName", 202, 1, 400, 1)` where 200 wide characters uses 400 bytes.

Comment: Pᴇʜ - VALUES (?, ?)  - didn't know that these question marks are valid to use, it's working, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to keep the line as

```vb
SQL = "INSERT INTO Tbl_Test VALUES (?, ?)"
```

and fill in the parameters into that SQL with

```vb
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@FileName", 20, 1, 0, 1)
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@MyFile", 204, 1, adoStream.Size, adoStream.Read)
```

using the [CreateParameter Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/createparameter-method-ado?view=sql-server-ver15) and the suitable data type for the data base fields.

Answer (score 0):

I would do that in this way:

```vb
SQL = "INSERT INTO Tbl_Test([FileName],[MyFile]) VALUES ('" & FileNameStr & "', CAST(" & adoStream.Read & ") as varbinary(max))"
```

**REMARK:**
NOT TESTED in VBA - I'm AutoIt coder, not VBA coder.